# iPhone Swipe UIKeyboard to Switch Views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, keyboard, swipe

I want to achieve something like this with my application and its keyboard.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajs1p5NCNw4 from 1:32 - 1:38. 
How can you hide your keyboard by swiping it horizontally and show another view on its place? Is it possible with default keyboard or should I create my own view with few buttons which I'll need and then add the swiping? (I know how to do this, but I'm not sure if apple wouldn't deny the app in app store because I implement my own keyboard or something like that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are custom views.  It might be a scroll view with paging enabled and two subviews (the numerical keypad is one subview and items view is the other subview).

The app might be using the custom view in place of the system keyboard, by setting the `inputView` property of a text field for example.  Or it might just be displaying the custom view as a subview of its top-level view.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant by creating a custom view, but won't apple deny this when I submit to app store? Isn't it against any policy to use my own keyboard instead of their default one?

Comment: It's not against policy.  [iOS Human Interface Guidelines: Keyboards and Input Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/TechnologyUsage/TechnologyUsage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH18-SW20)